# 'XDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Entry'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am working on a asp.net core web api 6.0 project.

When I try to write below query.

`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

```
_xDbContext.Entry<Holiday>(holiday).Collection(d => d.Deals)
            .Query()
            .Include(i => i.Deal)
            .Where(d => d.Deal.Status == true)
            .Load();
```

I got below error
`'IXDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no accessible extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type 'IXDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Application]`

.csproj

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />`

IXDbContext.cs

```
public interface IXDbContext
{ 
public DbSet<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class XDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IXDbContext
{
public DbSet<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have this interface? What is it good for? It's empty, it's no surprise there is no method Entry there. did you mean to use the class instead of the interface?

Comment: I've edited my question with `public DbSet<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }` . We are working on clean architecture. That's why we put Interface in Application layer, Then Implement inside infrastructure layer.

Comment: Well, `Entry` is still not part of that interface. `SaveChanges` isn't part of it either, so I guess there will be no permanent changes to your database in your code :) Please note that having an interface just for the sake of having an interface is not "clean code", it's bloat. You added something just for the sake of having it, with no functional purpose. I would question the choice of interface in this case.

Comment: The above query is working fine in asp.net core 3.1.  But It is not working in 6.0.
I did not added some code in questions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: It has nothing to do with Entity Framework, it is the interface you added.

Comment: You are not calling a method on a DbContext. You are calling a method on your interface. And it does not have that method.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.